# jquery mobile calender plugin not loading json data

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I bought this jQuery mobile calender plugin from envato market, the issue I have with it is that it does not detect my PHP generated JSON data.
Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$output = ' {"eid":"1","title":"just event test","image":"1426791253.png","discription":"Montes, sociosqu voluptate ultrices, conubia eiusmod? Beatae illum. Mattis, vestibulum aenean integer quasi nisi convallis egestas tristique id, nunc impedit. Eligendi magni, curae eligendi! Tempor purus sit sequi gravida dolor.","url":"","start":new Date("2015-02-22 14:00:00"),"end":new Date("2015-02-25 13:00:00")},
  {"eid":"1","title":"just event test","image":"1426791253.png","discription":"Montes, sociosqu voluptate ultrices, conubia eiusmod? Beatae illum. Mattis, vestibulum aenean integer quasi nisi convallis egestas tristique id, nunc impedit. Eligendi magni, curae eligendi! Tempor purus sit sequi gravida dolor.","url":"","start":new Date("2015-02-22 14:00:00"),"end":new Date("2015-02-25 13:00:00")},
  {"eid":"1","title":"just event test","image":"1426791253.png","discription":"Montes, sociosqu voluptate ultrices, conubia eiusmod? Beatae illum. Mattis, vestibulum aenean integer quasi nisi convallis egestas tristique id, nunc impedit. Eligendi magni, curae eligendi! Tempor purus sit sequi gravida dolor.","url":"","start":new Date("2015-02-22 14:00:00"),"end":new Date("2015-02-25 13:00:00")},
';

echo ($output);
?>
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();
var date3 = new Date();
var date4 = new Date();
var date5 = new Date();
var date6 = new Date();
var date7 = new Date();
var date8 = new Date();
var date9 = new Date();

date1.setDate(date1.getDate() - 30);
date2.setDate(date2.getDate() - 15);
date3.setDate(date3.getDate() - 13);
date4.setDate(date4.getDate() - 3);
date5.setDate(date5.getDate() + 5);
date6.setDate(date6.getDate() + 6);
date7.setDate(date7.getDate() + 12);
date8.setDate(date8.getDate() + 30);
date9.setDate(date9.getDate() + 38);

//var calEvents = "http://localhost/indicium/admin/data/app-calender.php";

var root = 'http://localhost/indicium/admin/data/app-calender.php';

$.ajax({
    url: root,
    method: 'GET',
    //dataType: 'JSONP'
}).then(function(data) {
    initCalendar(data);
});

function initCalendar(data) {
    alert(data);
  $("#calendar").jqmCalendar({
      events : data,
      months : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      days : ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
      startOfWeek : 1
   });
}
});
```

I just what help on this the javascript detects the data(json), I tried  debugging with alerting the data it alerted successfully, but in my browser console I see this (`Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined`);
Please help.

here is the calender javascript json data which works

```
var calEvents = [
    {"icon": "bars","eid":"1","title":"My event test","url":"#","start":new Date("2014-02-10T08:00:00.000Z"),"end":new Date("2014-02-10T10:00:00.000Z"),"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
    {"eid":" 1","title":"My event test","url":"#","start":new Date("2014-02-10T17:00:00.000Z"),"end":new Date("2014-02-10T18:00:00.000Z"),"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
    {"eid":"1","title":"My event 1","url":"#","start":date1,"end":date1,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
    {"icon": "info","eid":"2","title":"Event testing 2","url":"#","start":new Date("2015-04-03 18:54:00.000000"),"end":date3,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
    {"eid":"3","title":"My event 3","url":"#","start":date4,"end":date4,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
    {"icon": "alert","eid":"SomeID 4","title":"My event 4","url":"#","start":date5,"end":date6,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
    {"eid":"SomeID 5","title":"Just testing the calendar","url":"http://www.example.com","start":date7,"end":date7,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
    {"eid":"SomeID 6","title":"My event 6","url":"#","start":date8,"end":date8,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
    {"eid":"SomeID 7","title":"My event 7","url":"#","start":date9,"end":date9,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
];
```

Comment: Have you tried using .done instead of .then, is only one promise so it doesn't make much sense using then.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing of [] and, an unwanted comma at the end of json data. Use this:

```
<?php

$output = ' [{"eid":"1","title":"just event test","image":"1426791253.png","discription":"Montes, sociosqu voluptate ultrices, conubia eiusmod? Beatae illum. Mattis, vestibulum aenean integer quasi nisi convallis egestas tristique id, nunc impedit. Eligendi magni, curae eligendi! Tempor purus sit sequi gravida dolor.","url":"","start":new Date("2015-02-22 14:00:00"),"end":new Date("2015-02-25 13:00:00")},
  {"eid":"1","title":"just event test","image":"1426791253.png","discription":"Montes, sociosqu voluptate ultrices, conubia eiusmod? Beatae illum. Mattis, vestibulum aenean integer quasi nisi convallis egestas tristique id, nunc impedit. Eligendi magni, curae eligendi! Tempor purus sit sequi gravida dolor.","url":"","start":new Date("2015-02-22 14:00:00"),"end":new Date("2015-02-25 13:00:00")},
  {"eid":"1","title":"just event test","image":"1426791253.png","discription":"Montes, sociosqu voluptate ultrices, conubia eiusmod? Beatae illum. Mattis, vestibulum aenean integer quasi nisi convallis egestas tristique id, nunc impedit. Eligendi magni, curae eligendi! Tempor purus sit sequi gravida dolor.","url":"","start":new Date("2015-02-22 14:00:00"),"end":new Date("2015-02-25 13:00:00")}]';

echo ($output);
?>
```

Comment: i tried it didn't work, i think this issue is more that the json data, it might be the calender's javascript,

Comment: Then try echoing the worked json which you have posted above from the php

Comment: Not still working.your solution is correct i think it is the calender javascript;    i get (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined).